# MySQL AVG of TIMESTAMPDIFF function with WHERE CLAUSE

Tags: mysql, sql, timestamp, average

I have a table from which I am trying to get the average duration. I am using the following code

```
/*TIME DURATION*/
SELECT DATE(createDate),
AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, min(createDate), max(createDate))) AS Duration
FROM Impressions
WHERE session_id IN (
    SELECT session_id
    FROM carts
    WHERE createDate >= '2014-06-30'AND createDate < '2014-07-07'
        AND HOUR(createDate) >= 10
        AND HOUR(createDate) < 21
    )

AND session_Id <> ''
GROUP BY DATE(createDate);
```

However, I am getting the following error and cannot understand why. Any help will be appreciated.

> > ErrorCode: -2147467259, Number: 1111 
> >     ErrorMessage: Invalid use of group function

Comment: What is the type of `createDate`

Comment: The problem is MIN and MAX function nested in the AVG function. Too much grouping function. Infact if you remove MIN and MAX function you don't get any error.

Comment: @JorgeCampos: `createDate` is type `DATETIME`
@GiulioDeMarco: is there a work around? I need to calculate the duration, which is why the MIN and MAX were there.

Comment: What about you create a subquery with the `min` and `max` and the ´masterquery´ would do the average on this fields of the subquery ?!

Comment: Would you mind showing me an example? I am a complete newbie to mySQL so this will be a good learning opportunity

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend you to use the query like this:

```
SELECT DATE(tbl.createDate),
       AVG(TIMESTAMPDIFF(SECOND, tbl.minDt, tbl.maxDt)) AS Duration  
  FROM (SELECT DATE(i.createDate) as createDate,
               min(i.createDate) minDt,
               max(i.createDate) maxDt
          FROM Impressions i INNER JOIN
               carts c ON (i.session_id = c.session_id)
         WHERE c.createDate >= '2014-06-30' 
           AND c.createDate < '2014-07-07'
           AND HOUR(c.createDate) >= 10
           AND HOUR(c.createDate) < 21
           AND i.session_Id <> ''
         GROUP BY DATE(i.createDate) ) as tbl
 GROUP BY DATE(tbl.createDate);
```

Comment: Let me try this out, @Jorge. I have a hard time understanding JOINs. They seem pretty simple when I see the code, but when I try writing mine, things get messy. Is there a resource you can point out to that can help me? I learn best through examples and short exercises.

Comment: @eager_learner313 I've learned best pratices on SQL Joins over the years of experience (over 16 years by now) reading lots of articles and materials and of course making very big mistakes. So it would be difficult to point all of what I've read, but here on SO has a question to this: [Good methods or tutorials for understanding JOINs in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4017459/good-methods-or-tutorials-for-understanding-joins-in-sql) which I gave a quick look and find it very usefull and easy to understand.

Comment: This one is also very good: http://www.oaktable.net/content/sql-joins-visualized-surprising-way-0

Comment: Can you edit the post to fix a syntax error? There should be a comma after `DATE` in the `SELECT` statement.

Also, I am getting this error:
> ErrorCode: -2147467259, Number: 1054
> ErrorMessage: Unknown column 'tbl.createDate' in 'field list'

Comment: Own, my mistake. Done :)

Comment: I went ahead and made some other corrections. If you don't GROUP BY `createDate, session_id`, the correct average is not computed since we are looking at an average session length. Also, the `createDate` had an issue that I fixed :)

Comment: That's nice. The main thing is that you learn something new and this is my purpose here on SO, to help and to learn. :)

Comment: Oh I loved debugging it :) I am not new to programming; it's just that SQL is nothing like the procedural and objective languages I am used to. It's a new way of thinking. I am having a hard time reorienting myself. Also, if you can upvote the comment I made, that will be great!

Comment: there are still edits that need to be made for it to be the correct answer. I have those edits, but they aren't showing up. You need `group by` statements inside the `tbl`